# How can I make modifications to an HTML form that is automatically generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm creating a webform using a marketing automation platform. I want to add a field that functions with jquery to do an autocomplete. Unfortunately, the forms are generated through a WYSIWYG editor in the software, and then generated and put into the page when it renders. The only code for the form that appears in the HTML for the page is a simple variable placeholder - %%FORM::DEFINITION%% - which is then replaced with the form code when you visit the URL. The software support team tells me that making the change I want to make is impossible, which I see as a challenge.

The only thing I need to be able to do is add an id="autocomplete-dynamic"  attribute to the input on the form. I had two ideas how I could achieve this.

The first, and most preferable option, would be some script that runs at the bottom of the page that simply inserts the attribute into the input tag after the page renders out. This would only be a client-side change, but since all this does is make the text field capable of looking up values out of another table, it should be fine. If someone had a script blocker in place, they would not be prevented from typing into the text field normally, it's just that the auto-lookup wouldn't work. We're trying to make it easier to select an item from a list of thousands of possibilities, but if someone had to type in their own entry without the autocomplete, it would not be a disaster. This seems like a clean solution, but I am not sure if it can be done.

The other possibility is to get the form code out of the software and embed it in a separate HTML document, and make the change there. You can extract the raw HTML for the form for use on another page, but pasting this code right back into the landing page causes errors. So, the thought then was that if I have taken the code generated by the software and put it in an HTML page on a separate web server, I could modify it as needed, and then turn around and use an iframe to stick it right back in the landing page. The software shouldn't complain because the form is being used on an external site like it's supposed to be... I have just hidden that external site back inside the platform-hosted page.

Option 1 would still be much easier to implement, I think, provided it is actually possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution seems completely appropriate.

```
$(function() {
    $('#myForm input').attr('id', 'autocomplete-dynamic');
});
```

This can be added anywhere inside a script tag because it's wrapped in a shorthand document.ready function, which waits to run until the DOM is ready.